# Avoiding nested pattern matching (possibly with maybe monad)

Tags: f#

How could nested pattern matching, such as the following example, be re-written so that `None` is specified only once? I *think* the Maybe monad solves this problem. Is there something similar in the F# core library? Or, is there an alternative approach?

```
match a with
| Some b ->
    let c = b.SomeProperty
    match c with
    | Some d ->
        let e = d.SomeProperty
        //and so on...
    | None -> ()
| None -> ()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can solve this using built-in capabilities: **Option.bind**

```
type A = 
    member this.X : B option = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
and B =
    member this.Y : С option = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
and С =
    member this.Z : string option = Unchecked.defaultof<_>


let a : A = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
let v = 
    match 
        a.X 
        |> Option.bind (fun v -> v.Y) 
        |> Option.bind (fun v -> v.Z) with
    | Some s -> s
    | None -> "<none>"
```

Frankly, I doubt that introducing full-fledged 'maybe' implementation (via computation expressions) here can shorten the code.

**EDIT**: Dream mode - on

I think that version with *Option.bind* can be made smaller if F# has more lightweight syntax for the special case: lambda that refer to some member of its argument:

```
"123" |> fun s -> s.Length // current version
"123" |> #.Length // hypothetical syntax
```

This is how the sample can be rewritten in Nemerle that already has such capabilities:

```
using System;
using Nemerle.Utility; // for Accessor macro : generates property for given field

variant Option[T]
{
    | Some {value : T}
    | None
}

module OptionExtensions
{
    public Bind[T, U](this o : Option[T], f : T -> Option[U]) : Option[U]
    {
        match(o)
        {
            | Option.Some(value) => f(value)
            | Option.None => Option.None()
        }
    }
}

[Record] // Record macro: checks existing fields and creates constructor for its initialization  
class A
{   
    [Accessor]
    value : Option[A];
}

def print(_)
{
    // shortened syntax for functions with body -> match over arguments
    | Option.Some(_) => Console.WriteLine("value");
    | Option.None => Console.WriteLine("none");
}

def x = A(Option.Some(A(Option.Some(A(Option.None())))));
print(x.Value.Bind(_.Value)); // "value"
print(x.Value.Bind(_.Value).Bind(_.Value)); // "none"
```

Comment: I'm curious how you would handle this if the match expressions operated on different types, for instance the outer an option and the inner a list...the entire expression still returning an option.

Comment: can you give hypothetical sample: source code and what you want to get as a result?

Comment: Your "dream mode" syntax will likely become a reality one day https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506

Answer (score 6):

I like desco's answer; one should always favor built-in constructs.  But FWIW, here's what a workflow version might look like (if I understand the problem correctly):

```
type CE () =

  member this.Bind (v,f) =
    match v with
      | Some(x) -> f x
      | None -> None

  member this.Return v = v


type A (p:A option) =

  member this.P 
    with get() = p


let f (aIn:A option) = CE () {
  let! a = aIn 
  let! b = a.P 
  let! c = b.P 
  return c.P }

let x = f (Some(A(None)))

let y = f (Some(A(Some(A(Some(A(Some(A(None)))))))))

printfn "Your breakpoint here."
```

Comment: Actually, you can use mentioned build-in construct in your CE type. Just like `member this.Bind (v,f) = Option.bind f v`

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest this, but you can also solve it with exception handling:

```
try
    <code that just keeps dotting into option.Value with impunity>
with
    | :? System.NullReferenceException -> "None"
```

I just wanted to point out the rough equivalence of exception-handling to the Maybe/Either monads or `Option.bind`.  Typically prefer one of them to throwing and catching exceptions.

Comment: My example is a bit limiting. I'd also like to know how the more general case could be solved, that is, nested matching where the types are not all `option`.

Comment: I dont understand what you're after for the general case; perhaps you can post an example in a new question.

Comment: You could do it in a monad version by intermixing let and various signatures of let! (assuming they could be disambiguated).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Option.maybe` from FSharpx:

```
open FSharpx
type Pet = { Name: string; PreviousOwner: option<string> }
type Person = { Name: string; Pet: option<Pet> }

let pers = { Name = "Bob"; Pet = Some {Name = "Mr Burns"; PreviousOwner = Some "Susan"} }

Option.maybe {
    let! pet = pers.Pet
    let! prevOwner = pet.PreviousOwner 
    do printfn "%s was the previous owner of %s." prevOwner pet.Name
}
```

Output:

```
Susan was the previous owner of Mr Burns.
```

But, e.g. with this person instead there is just no output:

```
let pers = { Name = "Bob"; Pet = None }
```